# Calling a Stored Proc while Converting a Single Variable to XML

Tags: c#, xml, stored-procedures

I am trying to make an application that calls a stored procedure that logs error messages from other applications into a centralized database.  One of the requirements is to convert the stack trace data into XML format which I am having trouble constructing the method to do so (converting it from string to XML and then being able to pass it) and calling it appropriately in the other method. I've tried to look around the Internet for some answers but haven't gotten anything that conclusive.  Any help would be appreciated.

**this is the method I have so far to do the conversion:**

```
    public void XmlConverter() 
    {
        string result = "@StackTrace";

        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        StringReader read = new StringReader(result);
        read.Read();
        xd.Load(read);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        xd.WriteTo(xw);
        StringReader formatXml = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        XmlTextReader xmlRead = new XmlTextReader(formatXml);
        SqlXml sqlXml = new SqlXml(xmlRead);
        result += sqlXml;
}
```

**and this is what I have for the stored proc:**

```
       public int LogError(ApplicationErrorLog error, string ret)
    {
        XmlDocument res = new XmlDocument();
        string r;

        var guId = new SqlParameter("@GuId", error.GuId);
        var application = new SqlParameter("@Application", error.Application);
        var objectId = new SqlParameter("@ObjectId", error.ObjectId);
        var exceptionMessage = new SqlParameter("@ExceptionMessage", error.ExceptionMessage);
        var stackTrace = new SqlParameter("@StackTrace", error.StackTrace, r = res.XmlConverter());
        var createdBy = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", error.CreatedBy);
        var date = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDatetime", error.CreatedDateTime);
        return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec messageinsert @GuId,@Application,@ObjectId,@ExceptionMessage,@StackTrace,@CreatedBy,@CreatedDatetime",
          guId, application, objectId, exceptionMessage, stackTrace, createdBy, date);
    }
```

Comment: can you use this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153011/how-to-serialise-exception-object-as-xml-string

Comment: yes that looks quite helpful thank you.  How would you suggest I call it from within the " var stackTrace = new SqlParameter" line? or would there be a better place for it to be called? @flbas1

Comment: var stackTrace = new SqlParameter("@StackTrace", error.StackTrace.GetXmlString);